# Excel radio button not working on secondary monitors

Tags: excel, xlsm

I have an excel form with radio buttons that works fine on my device. However, the button either cannot be clicked on or work randomly whenever I try to use the form on my second & third monitor. Did anyone encounter a similar issue or knows how to solve this kind of issue?

I am using windows 11 and am using the following version of excel: Microsoft® Excel® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2308 Build 16.0.16731.20182) 64-bit

**Image of a part of the form**

[image: Image of a part of the form]

I noticed that some buttons were in between 2 different cells, i tried merging the 2 cells to see if that would solve the clickability issue but that did not solve the issue.

Comment: File -> Options -> General -> User interface options -> When using multiple displays -> Select "Optimize for compatibility". Restart.